# ¿Cómo contar las filas de una consulta MySQL en NodeJS?

Tags: mysql, nodejs

Intento contar cuántas filas tiene una consulta de MySQL que he hecho en NodeJS
*¿Cómo lo hago?*
Esta es la consulta:

```
    conexion.query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE user = 'Rex123';", function (filasQueHay) {
    isCreated = true;
    while (isCreated = true) {
        if (filasQueHay != null) {
            user = dogName + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
        } else {
            isCreated = false;
        }
    }
    
})
```

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado, por si alguien lo quiere saber hay que hacer lo siguiente

`SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM users;`